# C# - How to 'rollback' update in ItemUpdated event receiver in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

I have some code in an event receiver in ItemUpdated that checks for duplicates when an item is updated. I would like to if the item already exists after the changes, the updates are not applied. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
properties.ErrorMessage = "Custom Error Message";
properties.Cancel = true;
```

Place these 3 lines in a logical block which needs to stop the execution in the item updating event receiver. It will show the custom error message and stop updating.

Comment: Thank-you, but this does not work in my solution. It hits this code (I set breakpoints) but nothing is triggered.

Comment: It should be added in the ItemUpdating event receiver to have any effect.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. It should be itemUpdating.